# Resize Bitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

I resize a bitmap using the following code:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/mods.png");
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pict, (int)(pict.getWidth() / totScale),  
    (int)(pict.getHeight() / totScale), false);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
out.close();
```

The code for getting the bitmap from the camera that I am using is the following:

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            pict = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        }
});
```

The first picture is what I can see on the phone (in Astro file manager), and also when I draw the bitmap in my application on a canvas. This happens on every device I've tested on (HTC Legend and Galaxy Tab) The second picture is what it looks like on my computer. What is causing the blocks on the device?

### Solution:

Here is what fixed my problem:
Instead of

```
pict = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

I replaced that with

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();               
opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
pict = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opts);
```

[image: Phone]
[image: Computer]

Comment: Most sporting of you to take the time to post the exact solution (upvote).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Try changing the filter parameter from "false" to "true" in your call to createScaledBitmap().  I bet that will fix your problem.

You should read this article: http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/

Comment: Changing it to true helps a bit. I read the article, but how do I ensure my window and bitmap are both 32 bits, and both ARGB_8888?

Comment: @AmandeepGrewal If I understand correctly, the code you have included is working fine: you are snapping the photo, then creating a png file that looks fine on your computer.  The "problem" is in code that you are not showing us: the code you later use to read and display the photo. 1) Please show us that code.  2) Can you get any Android app to display the png file well?  How about Gallery? 3) In answer to your question, always use BitmapFactory with a method that allows you to specify BitmapFactory options, and always be sure to explicitly use ARGB_8888 for inPreferredConfig.

Comment: Well, I considered that code irrelevant as any Android app that I've tried (Gallery included) shows the blocks as shown in the picture. However, if you think the code is necessary, here it is in my onDraw:

    canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(pict, 0, 0, null);

Comment: P.S. Divers is right: png is a lossless format; when you use Bitmap.compress with Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, the quality parameter is ignored, so it "looks sloppy" to specify 90, it would "look better" to specify 100, which corresponds to reality.  See here for details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: Thanks! Specifying ARGB_888 worked! Image is now clear of any blocks!

Answer (score 2):

First and second pictures are the same.

P.S.

```
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
```

You cant compress PNG format, only JPEG.