# Android scale to a Bitmap

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resize a BitMap in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android)

Can anyone show me how to scale a `Bitmap` object in `Android`. I want to change the height and width of the bitmap object to fit an `ImageView`.

Kind Regards

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please do at least a little research and show effort before asking a question.  If you read the documentation for ImageView, you will find this in less time than it took me to write this comment. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can scale your bitmap to required size:

```
   Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realBitmap,imageWidth, imageHeight, true);
```

Here you can give imageWidth and imageHeight according to your need. "realBitmap" is the real bitmap you have and "bitmap" is the Bitmap returned after scaling.

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) it is . please do some homework on your own