# Avoiding out of memory error in loading bitmap in listview

Tags: android, android-memory

I am having an listview and i am loading bitmaps in it from the web .. but now the problem is  i am having 1000 item in the listview so, it is causing me out of memory error.. i have used the image caching also..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using any one of the below will solve your problem

[Lazy List](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

[Universal ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```
   public class ListFivePictureNameDetailsPassFail extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new StudentListAdapter(this));
}

private class StudentListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mStudents = { "DurgaPrasad", "Raghu", "Vivek",
            "Satish", "Naga Jyothi", "Vardhika", "Nikhil" };
    private String[] mDetailsStudent = { "Details of DurgaPrasad",
            "Details of  Raghu This row is not created using java",
            "Details of Vivek", "Details of Satish",
            "Details of Naga Jyothi", "Details of Vardhika",
            "Details of Nikhil" };

    public StudentListAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mStudents.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            System.out.println("111111111111 : "+position);
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            /*if (position == 0) {
                System.out.println("111111111111 : "+position);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.studentdetailsrow, null);
                System.out.println("111111111111 : "+position);
            } else*/
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.studentdetailsrowother, null);
        }

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon2);
        if (position == 0) {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.newicon);
            iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        } else {
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.newicon);
            iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        }

        TextView tvname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.stuname);
        TextView tvdetail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.studetail);
        tvname.setText(mStudents[position]);
        tvdetail.setText(mDetailsStudent[position]);
        return v;
    }
};

   }
```

Comment: Sorry !! i didn't get u.. but i have also used view holder pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to minimize the memory usage by scaling the images down as much as possible. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837803/356224) is an example on how to do that.

Comment: That's a nice soultion. but wouldn;t that will hurt performace.