# android - large images cause app crash

Tags: android, image, graphics

I'm working on a tablet app. I tried to set high-resolution (2223x3553) images as background using `Layout.setBackgroundResource(ResId)`. The app crashed while testing on `Nexus 7`, I won't paste the stack traces since there were like 8 or 9 exceptions with about 300 red lines in the `LogCat` and it took me a while to figure out the reason. I got it after I noticed the `OutOfMemoryException`, using 1280x800 images the app runs fine but some quality loss has occurred since those images are designed to be high-res.

The question: how to handle high-resolution images in Android to prevent crashes like that? All images are local and stored in the `drawable` folder

Comment: You need to resize the image before load it to memory. This answer may be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android

Comment: FYI a bitmap of that height and width will require about 30 megabytes of java heap.

Comment: @Maver1ck Have you tried the tutorial , You need to calculate the sample size and based on that you need load the image please check the tutorial...

Comment: Nexus-7 is only 1280×800. Your background image is over killed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use same library that I have used in such a **Use Case** ,

[This project](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/) will help you in yours also. Because **you need to compress the images while displaying them** and also use the capability of lazy loading if you need eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Image sizes are limited in android development. You can not use images which are bigger than the prescribed ones. There is a guideline about how to choose images for your application. This is the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to the guidelines.