# Using BitmapFactory.Options();

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have taken and modified some code used to get a high quality anti-aliased small version of a larger (500x500) bitmap image. Apparently using a Matrix produces higher quality than employing createScaledBitmap(). The results were not very impressive.. and I suspected that perhaps I had made a mistake, in particularl I was unsure as to whether the options thing was actually being employed. So I changed the `inSampleSize = 1;` to `inSampleSize = 50;` expecting to see a dramatic drop in quality, but there was no change. So now I suspect options is being ignored. Can this code be rescued?

I was hoping to perhaps find some version of createBitmap which took bith a `bitmap` and an `options` argument, but could find none.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = true;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inDither = false;
options.inSampleSize = 1;
options.inScaled = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

Bitmap bmpSource = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bigicon);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(.1f,.1f);
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpSource, 0, 0, bmpSource.getWidth(), bmpSource.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well you should actually provide it as parameter. Change

```
Bitmap bmpSource = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bigicon);
```

with

```
Bitmap bmpSource = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bigicon, options);
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this [Creating a scaled bitmap with createScaledBitmap in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839388/creating-a-scaled-bitmap-with-createscaledbitmap-in-android/17839597#17839597)

This too: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html