# CWAC Camera: why my SimpleCameraHost saveImage is so slow, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: android, camera, compression, commonsware-cwac, webp

How to optimize this peace of code?
It takes about a minute on `saveImage` method.

```
class ObrolSimpleHost extends SimpleCameraHost {
  private final String[] SCAN_TYPES = {"image/webp"};
  private Context context = null;

  public ObrolSimpleHost(Context _ctxt) {
    super(_ctxt);
    this.context = getActivity();
  }

  @Override public void saveImage(PictureTransaction xact, Bitmap bitmap) {
    File photo = getPhotoPath();
    if (photo.exists()) {
      photo.delete();
    }
    try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 70, fos);
      fos.flush();
      fos.getFD().sync();
      if (scanSavedImage()) {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{photo.getPath()}, SCAN_TYPES, null);
      }
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
      handleException(e);
    }
  }

  @Override public void saveImage(PictureTransaction xact, byte[] image) {
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

I am calling `ObrolSimpleHost` from CameraFragment:

```
PictureTransaction xact = new PictureTransaction(getHost());
xact.needBitmap(true);
takePicture(xact);
```

Comment: Use Traceview and find out exactly where your problem lies. I would recommend you not write to `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then convert to a `byte[]`, then write the `byte[]` to a `FileOutputStream`. Just pass the `FileOutputStream` to `compress()`. If nothing else, that will help with memory management.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you I have edited the code. Does it look better now?

Comment: That's an improvement. You may want to `flush()` the `FileOutputStream` just before you `sync()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you, I just edited the code. Yes, it does look much much better.

Comment: @CommonsWare looks like it is Android issue with `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 70, fos);` One option I can consider is to reduce image size. Right know, the image size is over **2-3MB** on my device. The question is, how to reduce this `bitmap` itself so, the end image will be smaller and make faster compression process?

Comment: "how to reduce this bitmap itself so" -- If you mean that you want the image to have fewer pixels, use `createScaledBitmap()` on `Bitmap`, I guess. I haven't played with this personally.

Comment: @CommonsWare it works. By resizing bitmap, compression time is lessened. Thank you for your advice and library.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added my code as answer bellow. Does createScaledBitmap() part is makes sense?

Comment: "is makes sense?" -- I have no idea. As I wrote, I have not used `createScaledBitmap()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare anyway thank you very much for your [cwac-camera](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) library. It is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own answer.

#### Fixed issues which `CommonsWare` mentioned and resize `bitmap` before compression by `createScaledBitmap`:

```
class ObrolSimpleHost extends SimpleCameraHost {
  private final String[] SCAN_TYPES = {"image/" + imputType};
  private Context context = null;

  public ObrolSimpleHost(Context _ctxt) {
    super(_ctxt);
    this.context = getActivity();
  }

  @Override public void saveImage(PictureTransaction xact, Bitmap bitmap) {
    File photo = getPhotoPath();
    String path = photo.getPath().replace("jpg", imputType);
    if (photo.exists()) {
      photo.delete();
    }

    /**
     * Resizing bitmap, so save some ms in compression
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839388/creating-a-scaled-bitmap-with-createscaledbitmap-in-android
     */
    final int maxSize = 960;
    int outWidth;
    int outHeight;
    int inWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int inHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    if(inWidth > inHeight){
      outWidth = maxSize;
      outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
    } else {
      outHeight = maxSize;
      outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
    }
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, outWidth, outHeight, false);

    try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
      if (imputType.equals("jpeg")) {
        resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos);
      } else {
        resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 70, fos);
      }
      fos.flush();
      fos.getFD().sync();
      if (scanSavedImage()) {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{photo.getPath()}, SCAN_TYPES, null);
      }
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
      handleException(e);
    }
    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new Events.PreparingBitmapEvent(path));
    getActivity().finish();
  }

  @Override public void saveImage(PictureTransaction xact, byte[] image) {
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

#### Instead of standard `bitmap` use other library which build with [JNI](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html)

In my case I am going to try [Roid-WebP](https://github.com/RincLiu/Roid-WebP)