# Android - how to set a large bitmap to ImageSpan?

Tags: android, rich-text-editor, imagespan

I try to set a large `bitmap(720*18463)` to `ImageSpan`, but it didn't appear, and the problem is :

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (720x18463, max=4096x4096)
```

How to deal with it ?

**(Addtional, I want to make a RichText Editor, which can add image around text.)**

Comment: use createScaledBitmap to decrease size of your bitmap

Comment: @kaitian521 But I actually need every pixel, and I know ImageView Widget may do it without decreasing.Is there any way to load it in ImageSpan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale your Bitmap when decode, and wrap it with a BitmapDrawable if you want to control the bounds.

Comment: What is the difference with my answer, which was given half hour before your one?

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense to put `18463` pixels bitmap on a screen, because it's large then any screen existed on market. You must to scale it down in order to make it works. In order to scale it down, please check [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839388/creating-a-scaled-bitmap-with-createscaledbitmap-in-android).

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to scale it down (maybe 72*1846) but also render it in full-width (like 720p/1080p). I know **scaleType** of the ImageView  is an example, and what about ImageSpan?

Comment: Get width of screen and scale down it to that size.

Comment: The Width of Image is now 720 and almost fit the screen width of Nexus 4 which is my test device.

Comment: @2BAB why you accepted another answer if it's the same as mine, but was given half hour latter?

Comment: I got the point of decreasing from you (thanks for this), but not Drawable$setBounds that solve my problem.