# Google Cloud Messaging Notification icon small

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I want to make bigger my gcm notification icon which seems near the notification in gcm application. I resize it inside my project but still it seems small when notification is came. What can I do to make it bigger ? Thanks in advance.

I tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030710/gcm-push-notification-large-icon-size) but that did not work. When I used it icon never show up, default icon showed up.

Comment: follow the guide about app notification icon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCM Push Notification Large Icon size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030710/gcm-push-notification-large-icon-size)

Comment: That did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Notification icons

22 × 22 area in 24 × 24 (mdpi)

33 × 33 area in 36 × 36 (hdpi)

44 × 44 area in 48 × 48 (xhdpi)

66 × 66 area in 72 × 72 (xxhdpi)

88 × 88 area in 96 × 96 (xxxhdpi) (.png format)

these ere the fixed sizes. if you use larger icons, these will be fixed.

as seen on [here](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/)

Comment: In the same phone another application's icon size is much more large than mine, how they can do it? Shouldnt they be same?

Comment: could u send your icon? maybe there is a problem with its sizes.

Comment: I am not able to send because team leader does not let me. But sizes are 512x 512 px