# How to resize image with Picasso before upload to server?

Tags: android, image-uploading, picasso, loopj

I am uploading images with loopj.

```
params.put("file_"+key+"", new File(String.valueOf(value.getOriginalPath())));
```

but i want to resize image before upload. Is there a way to resize image "on the fly" - without resizing->saving to SD->uploading? just resize im memory and upload - InputStream?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Bitmap`s `createScaledBitmap()` as explained e.g. here

How about this one: [How to Resize a Bitmap in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android)

EDIT - Sending bitmap to server

A bitmap in memory is quite large as it is not compressed like a PNG or JPEG, instead for every pixel you need 3 or even 4 bytes of memory. Thus you'll want to convert that bitmap into e.g. an PNG before uploading. This can be done with the [Bitmap.compress(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)) method, which requires an OutputStream to write the compressed image to. As you do not want to save the image to SD card before uploading, you can use an `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead to keep the compressed image in memory.

Then, you can attach an `ByteArrayInputStream` to the bytes written and pass that to loopj.

In code this should look something like so:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outStream);
ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray());

/* ...and then pass inStream loopj */
```

Comment: ok i scaled image `Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
profileImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 120, 120, false)); ` but how to put it into loopj params? it supports InputStream, File, ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: I added an example on how to do that to the answer.

Comment: got an OutOfMemoryError on  `AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                          client.post(HERE);`   is  there a simple and right way to upload pictures on server?

Comment: I don't know loopj that well. Have you checked their documentation?

Comment: i just need a simple and right way to upload resized image to server. is there a good example or algoritm? 1. resize image 2. save it to temp dir??? as i see it costs too much memory to store images in memory, as i need more than 3 images at once to upload 3. upload image

Comment: You can create a temp file and change the example from above so that outStream and inStream go to that temp file instead of the in-memory byte array.

Comment: Why this method create a local file in memory of the user?

Answer (score 0):

```
Target mTarget = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
        Log.d("!!!!!",">>>>>>>>>>>>");
        SaveImage.SaveImageFromBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {
        Log.d("!!!!!","--------");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {

    }
};
File file = new File(value.getOriginalPathString());
Picasso.with(AddSpa.this).load(file).resize(800,0).into(mTarget);
```