# Android: ShowCaseView, OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, showcaseview

When using [amlcurran/ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView), It's work fine , but for devices with extra-high density screens, makes OutOfMemoryError problem :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1511): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:787)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:754)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.ShowcaseView.updateBitmap(ShowcaseView.java:188)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.ShowcaseView.access$3(ShowcaseView.java:184)
/AndroidRuntime(1511):  at com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview.ShowcaseView$UpdateOnGlobalLayout.onGlobalLayout(ShowcaseView.java:617)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:815)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1778)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime(1511):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

does anyone have solve this problem?

Comment: clearly your bitmap is very large try scaling the bitmap to appropriate size first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android

Comment: this can help http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html