# Do not show images of ImageView in real devices

Tags: java, android

I want show image in ImageView, but don't show it. I use XML code and Java code but don't show. show in simulator but in real devices don't show.
 tested on LG G2, HTC One X, Samsung Galaxy S3.

my xml code :

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sms_dialog_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="@drawable/show_sms_header" />
```

my java code :

```
        Dialog_Header_Img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sms_dialog_header);
    Dialog_Header_Img.setImageResource(R.drawable.show_sms_header);
```

I used to be separated from each.

Please tell me the solution

Comment: Are you sure that `R.drawable.show_sms_header` exists and is correct?

Comment: You have a background pre-defined in your XML and also setting the image as resource in java code? This shouldn't be the problem though.

Comment: @JonasCz : yes, you can see this link : http://s15.postimg.org/7no94xxy3/Dont_Show_In_Image_View.jpg

Comment: what is the size of the image?

Comment: @Carnal : I use Xml code and Java code! but don't show! I use this codes anywhere, but this where don't show

Comment: What is the resolution of the image?

Comment: @Fahim : image size has 240kb

Comment: @JonasCz : 1920 * 1080

Comment: @Mohammad try optimizing the resolution of the image and check

Comment: Try resizing it to something smaller, eg. 300 x 200.

Comment: Try setting a color as a background to begin with in XML just to see if it is showing up.

Comment: @JonasCz , Fahim and more dear firend : Low resolution image, and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should set image in xml by code:

```
android:src="@drawable/show_sms_header"
```

not by `android:background`, well you can set background to color or other image but your main image you should set by `android:src`

If you changing something about your image, leave first line in your code that you show, and delete second, if setting image is only thing you set, then you can delete both, because you set source of image in xml.

Comment: Like others guys are saying, try optimize your image. By create a few images in different drawable folder or change resolution of image pragmatically, for example like there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android

Answer (score 0):

The "src" attribute should be set to your drawable if you want it to be "centerCrop" correctly.

Check this out :

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sms_dialog_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/show_sms_header" />
```

Make sure that your file, called "show_sms_header", is in your drawable ( /res/drawable) directory.