# Camera Capture Image is not clear(Blurry) in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmapimage, android-camera-intent, blurry

I Have a Problem with the Camera Capture Image.its set blurry.

I searched lots of but i can't Get Solutions

I don't know How to solve issue

Here is My Code Which i Used For Camera Capture Image

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  img1.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

    Bitmap bm;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
    int scale = 1;
    while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
            && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale *= 2;
    options.inSampleSize = scale;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);

    img1.setImageBitmap(bm);

}
```

The Gallery Image Set Good in Imageview But Its Only Happen with the CameraCapture Imageview
[Camera Capture Image is not clear(Blurry) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229811/camera-capture-image-is-not-clearblurry-in-android)

Help Me for this issue.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here

```
thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, bytes);
```

Second paramater in .compress() method is quality which can be in range 0..100.
You have set it to 0 -> maximum compression.

Change the value to a higher value.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is getting thumbnail nail out of intent data that's why it is blurry

Try This :
    File mImageFile is path where you want to store you camera image file.

```
    mImageFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "DCIM" + File.separator + "temp.png"); 

Uri tempURI = Uri.fromFile(mImageFile);
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempURI);
activity.startActivityForResult(i, CHOOSE_CAMERA_RESULT);


then in your onActivityResult

@Override
public void onActivityResultRAW(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResultRAW(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode)
    {
    case CHOOSE_CAMERA_RESULT:
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            // here you image has been save to the path mImageFile.
            Log.d("ImagePath", "Image saved to path : " + mImageFile.getAbsoultePath());
        }
    }
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i hava a Two Option Gallery or Camera SO How Can i Modified it.Help me to Modifi this.@dex

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);   I used this for Open Camera @dex

Comment: @RushangPrajapati : once you click on camera button , call startCamera Activity code , once click is over then in OnActivityResult you can get the image ...process accordingly. For gallery you can invoke gallery via Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*"); startActivityForResult(intent, Gallery_code) , then in onActivityResult you will get URI , openInputStream from that uri to get the bitmap of image.

Comment: mImageFile is path where you will store you capture image. for example  mImageFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "DCIM" + File.separator + "temp.png");  means  capture image will be store in inside /sdcard/DCIM/ folder. you can give any path.

Comment: I Set All things But it shows "Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3120x4160, max=4096x4096)" How to Compress Bitmap ??

Comment: @RushangPrajapati : you need to re-size your bitmap so that it can fit in 1024 * 1024 or what ever memory available. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android

Comment: How can i Resize Bitmap ? @dex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97672/discussion-between-dex-and-rushang-prajapati).

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get bitmap from data.getExtras object in onActivityResult then it returns bitmap with low quality, below solution is complete followup Android Documentation. Don`t forget to write permission in Manifest.

```
lateinit var currentPhotoPath: String
var photoFile: File? = null
private fun takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        .also { takePictureIntent ->
            photoFile = try {
                createImageFile()
            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                null
            }

            photoFile?.also {
                fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this, "com.example.fileprovider",
                    it
                )
                AppLogger.d("asad_fileUri", "$fileUri")
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri)
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CommonUtils.CAMERA)
            }
        }

}


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    try {
        if (requestCode == CommonUtils.CAMERA) {
            galleryAddPic()
            setPic()?.let {
                fileUri = getImageUri(this, it)
            }
            postImagesAdapter.addItems(
                listOf(PostImagesModel(fileUri.toString(), false, fileUri)), false
            )

        } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show()
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}

// File path xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images"
        path="/" />
</paths>

//AndroidManifest
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_path"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

[Take Photos](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)