# i want to resize my captured image up to 50 KBs -60 KBs before saving it? How can it be done?

Tags: android

This is a simple camera app i have made, i want to resize my picture from original size to some where in between 50 to 60 KBs before saving it in galary. what are the various ways to do this? Thanks for the help!
  `

```
public class ImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

    this.imageview = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
    if (requestcode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultcode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageview.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10703256/1058365

Comment: used the compress image method....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this.

```
public static Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Bitmap b, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
        {
            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, reqWidth, reqHeight), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), m, true);
        }

//call this method like
    Bitmap bmp=getScaledBitmap(bm,50,50);
```

its helpfull for you.

Answer (score 1):

**onActivityResult**

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
if (requestcode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultcode == RESULT_OK) {
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");


  Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        mPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex).toString();
        System.out.println("picturePath" + mPath);

        cursor.close();

}
 }
```

**First take Your path and call function**

```
String   mImageNewPath=compressImage(mPath);
```

mImageNewPath is the path of Comress image or New Image Of compressed image without loosing quality

**function To Reduce size without Loosing quality**

```
    public String compressImage(String imageUri) {

    String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
    int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

    float maxHeight = 816.0f;
    float maxWidth = 612.0f;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {               imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);               actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;             } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
        imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
        actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
        actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
        actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
        actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

        }
    }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

    try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
        matrix.postRotate(180);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
        matrix.postRotate(270);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
            scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
            true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String filename = getFilename();
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filename;

    }

    public String getFilename() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "Visitor Management/VisitorPicture");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "IMG_"+System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    return uriSting;

    }
    private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
    Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
    }
    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height/ (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;      }       final float totalPixels = width * height;       final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;       while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize++;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
    }
```

you used the compress image now and also if you want delete the capture image before compress, you need to delete it with the function

```
    if(new File(mPath).exists())
    {
        new File(mPath).delete();
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be very complex and long. I'm just a beginner. Is there any simplest way to resize?