# Cannot set high resolution image(1920x1280) to image view on android 7.0

Tags: android, crash, imageview, runtime-error, android-7.0-nougat

I run this app lot of devices. less than android 7 and more than android 7, that is fine. but when i run this app on samsung s6(android 7.0) it gives this error

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw
>   too large(120422400bytes) bitmap.
>          at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
>          at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1420)
>          at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
>          at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:18591)
>          at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:18527)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18315)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17302)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18086)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17297)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18086)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17297)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18086)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17297)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18086)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17297)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18086)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17297)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18086)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18327)
>          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:919)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17302)
>          at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
>          at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:698)
>          at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:806)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3135)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2931)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2523)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1522)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7098)
>          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
>          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
>          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
>          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Answer (score 0):

Move your image in the (hi-res) drawable to drawable-xxhdpi and largeheap=true in manifest file.

Comment: thanks Jayas for your replay. I did that too but it didn't work

Comment: @J.D for large images, only libraries like Picasso or Glide seem to work. Otherwise you allocate too much RAM and the app crashes with OOME.

Answer (score 0):

it will throw OutOfMemory error if you try to show too large image in android ,you have to scale it down or resize ,look into this

[How to Resize a Bitmap in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android)