# issue in OutOfMemoryError - Android

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I'm getting following error. I have tried  `android:largeHeap="true"` and `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`. But still `app` is crashing and showing the same error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 39306252 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 27MB until OOM

at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)

at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
```

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError in ANdroid Studio`. In Android Studio? Not in an Android app on your Android device?

Comment: I think you are caching many image assets or something like that in your app.

Comment: refer this answer, you'll get an idea about OOM > https://stackoverflow.com/a/32245018/6630837

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio/32245018#32245018

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23970828 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your BitMap size is large then you have to resize/rescale it to show it in your app otherwise OutOfMemory error will be thrown , you can try to use

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

in your manifest or you have to manually resize them in your code ,have a look
[How to Resize a Bitmap in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android)

Comment: The OP already mentioned about `android:largeHeap="true"`.

Comment: Besides, `largeHeap` has no effect with large images, It's too big allocation over too short time, for large images the only thing that works is using something like Glide or Picasso.

Comment: @Zoe, No. Just resizing/rescaling will do. That would be done by them too.

Comment: @greenapps what if OP **wants** to have a massive image? In that case, resizing isn't an option and largeHeap can't possibly handle it

Comment: Indeed. But then Glide and Picasso wil not master either.

Comment: @greenapps It won't work perfectly, but it still does better than just using `largeHeap`.

Comment: @Enzokie when i answered it wasn't , it was edited after may be.

Comment: @himel it's already in the question from the beginning, the edit history shows it.