# Reduce the image size while saving to local folder android

Tags: android, image, android-bitmap

I want to reduce the image size while saving it to local folder. Now it is stored with its original size. I am storing the whole bitmap to path as below:

```
                String fileName = "image_" + count++ + ".png";

                System.out.println("file name is : " + fileName);

                File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File folder = new File(sd + "/Wallpaper Pack");
                System.out.println("folder is : " + folder);
                folder.mkdir();

                File dest = new File(folder, fileName);
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out;
                    out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: in bitmap.compress() change 50 to some lower value like 30 , 20.. It should help.

Answer (score 0):

Resize your `Bitmap`. Take a look at [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10703256/3416163). Also when using PNG format here `(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, out);` compression won't happen. It's always 100, so you can change output format to JPEG.

Comment: ok..but in jpeg can image gets stored in less size??..#Anton Kazakov

Comment: @rs11read my answer one more time. 1 reduce resolution 2. use compress factor in (Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, COMPRESS FACTOR, out)