# How to resize a bitmap in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I have an immutal Bitmap and I'am not able to resize (Immutable bitmap crash error).

```
myImage = task.execute(List1.get(i)).get();
myImage.setWidth(400);
myImage.setHigth(400);
List2.add(myImage);
```

> Error: only mutable bitmaps may be reconfigured

Does anyone have a neat solution for this?

Comment: This one helped me out:
[Resize a Bitmap in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10703256/9740071) Hope I could help you out.

Comment: This one helped me out: [Resize Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10703256/9740071) Hope I could help you out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Resize a Bitmap in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android)

Comment: @Vasco what did help you out?