# How to resize image before loading to ImageView to avoid OOM issues

Tags: java, android, bitmap

How can i resize image before loading to imageview after selecting from gallery/photos?. Otherwise large images are causing OOM issues.

```
SelectImageGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image From Gallery"), 1);
    }
}
```

```
Uri uri = I.getData();
    try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Resize a Bitmap in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android)

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudAbuElheja. How do I implement this in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it to resolve it using glide as follows for those who might need it in future.
Selecting Intent

```
SelectImageGallery1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image1 From Gallery"), 1);
    }
}
```

Setting Image to Imageview Using Glide

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int RC, int RQC, Intent I) {
        super.onActivityResult(RC, RQC, I);
        if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = I.getData();
            RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

            Glide.with(this)
                    .setDefaultRequestOptions(options)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(uri)
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>(512, 512) {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap1, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
                            MainActivity.this.bitmap1 = bitmap1;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Bitmap resized_Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap( resized_Bitmap);
```

Comment: Thamk you @anehme. Unfortunately it is not resizing before loading to imageView

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/) blog post

you can resize your bitmap like this

> ```
> import android.graphics.Matrix
>
> public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
>     int width = bm.getWidth();
>     int height = bm.getHeight();
>     float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
>     float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
>     // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
>     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
>     // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
>     matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
>
>     // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
>     Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
>         bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
>     bm.recycle();
>     return resizedBitmap;
> }
> ```

Comment: Kindly share how to implement in several imageviews in one activity

Answer (score 0):

As you facing OOM issue, you can remove this issue by

1) Decrease size of bitmap and

2) Increase size of app by changing in gradle.properties and AndroidManifest file

**gradle.properties**
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

**Android Manifest**         android:largeHeap="true",         android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Comment: Thanks @webaddicted i understand that android:largeHeap="true",  and android:hardwareAccelerated="true" have other issues like slowing down the app. I tried it though didn't work at some point

share