# Android, change Bitmap aspect ratio programmatically

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I found a lot of code about Bitmaps in Android. Change size, change size preserving aspect ratio, compress etc. etc.
However I need to change a Bitmap aspect ratio to fit my needs (5:8), programmatically.
I have no code to show because any search I made return how to preserve aspect ratio, not to change it.
As for example, 5:8 should be width:500 height:800

Comment: As I can read this is exactly the opposite to my needs. I don't need to preserve the aspect ratio, I need to change the aspect ratio to 5:8 (or any other I should decide) without caring if the image will be deformed.

Comment: I stand corrected - Removed

Comment: It's the same. Calculate needed width and height, and 
`newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(oldBitmap, width, height, true);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Resize a Bitmap in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android)

Comment: @RyanMentley To resize, yes. However in my answer I also calculate the desired aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SergeyGlotov comment I simply calculated the new size this way:

```
    private Bitmap bitmapChangeAspectRatio(Bitmap bitmap){
        int width, height;
        width = bitmap.getWidth() / 5;
        height = width * 8;
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), height, true);
    }
```

I do not delete the question due there is not a clear example of this on the web.