# How to resize bitmap that have in drawable layer-list? Programmatic or in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, bitmap

I am trying to build Splash Screens the Right Way like this https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-a-splash-screen-on-android-the-right-way-93d6fb444857 for that i have to place my app icon .png file inside a drawable layer list as bitmap like this

```
<item
    android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
</item>
```

Now how can i resize this bitmap? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to reset a new resize through XML, and you can confirm this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#BitmapFile).

In the code method, there are different and complex methods. If you want to know more, you can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android)

> But if your goal is only to change the size, this can be done through **ImageView**

if you want full image set to your scree (best for splash screen) that use match_parent to image view , This method is easier and faster than other methods:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/splash_screen" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```