# Android custom Icon for shortcut

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Saimiri_sciureus-1_Luc_Viatour.jpg");        
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, bitmap);
```

After reading this post. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3331194/2746924
but the icon is simply not being displayed.
I don't want to use Resource from context.
How can I use a bitmap?